# SerenityBDD: Wrong scenario outline report text and test filename length issue

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I'm creating a PoC with SerenityBDD + Cucumber and I've found that with a simple example using Scenario Outlines, the report generated doesn't show the correct Scenario Outline text and the gradle task fails due the generated test file name length.

For the file name length, I've set the *serenity.compress.filenames* to true, but didn't work.

The sample project code can be found here:

https://github.com/ehdez73/web-testing/tree/serenity-bdd/serenity-bdd

The stacktrace and a report screenshot with the errors remarked can be found under the docs folder:

```
https://github.com/ehdez73/web-testing/blob/serenity-bdd/serenity-bdd/doc/build-stacktrace.txt#L125
https://github.com/ehdez73/web-testing/blob/serenity-bdd/serenity-bdd/doc/scenario-outline-report-with-errors.png
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the JUnit reports that Gradle generates, not the Serenity reports.

Regarding the Scenario Outline, Serenity does what it can to restore the variables, but Cucumber actually gives very little information about the variables, so Serenity sometimes gets it wrong. It might work better if the variables where surrounded by blank spaces.